# How to initialize a member function pointer with member function

Tags: c++

I want to create a compare function (cmp) for my class. It is good if the constructor have a function parameter. if not I want to set a default for it, any ideas?

there is my code below,

```
template<class T>
class BinaryHeap{
public:
    BinaryHeap();
    explicit BinaryHeap(bool (*cmp)(T, T));
private:
    bool (*cmp)(T ele_a, T ele_b); // function pointer
    bool default_cmp(T ele_a, T ele_b);
};
template<class T>
BinaryHeap<T>::BinaryHeap() {
    //the code bellow is not work;
    this->cmp = default_cmp; // there is problem
}
template<class T>
BinaryHeap<T>::BinaryHeap(bool (*cmp)(T, T)) {
    heap_size = 0;
    this->cmp = cmp; // this is ok for the compiler
}
```

Comment: A member function needs an object to be called on (what becomes the `this` pointier inside the function). Your `cmp` variable is a pointer to a ***non***-member function. For a simple solution I recommend you do some research about [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change this

```
bool default_cmp(T ele_a, T ele_b);
```

to this

```
static bool default_cmp(T ele_a, T ele_b);
```

Regular member functions are not compatible with function pointers, but static member functions are.

Comment: Thanks, is there any better way to optimizer it?

Comment: @Harry Optimize in what sense? It would be better to pass your objects as references `explicit BinaryHeap(bool (*cmp)(const T&, const T&));` etc. I'd also question the whole approach. The standard library uses a template parameter for comparison functions which defaults to `std::less<T>`. So `template<class T, class Cmp = std::less<T>>
class BinaryHeap{`. That's more flexible (unless you have particularly special requirements for your comparison function).

Comment: thanks for you reply. I am learning more about standard library.

Comment: @Harry The advantage of making the comparision a template parameter is that you can then use any type for your comparision, function pointer, std::function, functor, etc.